# Supporting USB in Retro PC's BIOS to use modern USB keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboards

I have my retro PC with the MSI MS-6119 (chipset Intel BX, Slot 1) motherboard. I have a very cheap PS2 keyboard that works as expected but I would like to invest in a brand new PS2 keyboard from Windows 95/98 era, but these are rare.

I have found one from the similar era, but it has USB connection, not PS2. Can I use it so that it will work the same way as PS2 keyboard in BIOS, DOS, boot menu etc.?

When I go to the **BIOS**, under **Integrated Peripherals** I can see it has the **USB Keyboard Support** option, does making it **Enabled**, allow me to use any USB keyboard (even a modern one) as a PS2 one?

Any downsides?

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to Hardware Recs. This seems to be bordering on the line of "tech support" vs. hardware recommendation; I'll leave it open for now, but I'm not entirely sure we can give a recommendation for a keyboard without knowing whether you want to go the USB or PS2 route. USB and PS2 keyboards operate on fundamentally different principles (polled vs. interrupts), but this usually doesn't matter so long as the platform supports them. Have you tried using a USB keyboard to see if it works for your purposes? That's probably the simplest, easiest, and fastest thing.